# Issues with updating Azure SQL database with a new column with .NET backend Mobile App Service

Tags: c#, android, sql, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am newly building a mobile app with Azure cloud services. I followed the tutorial at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started

I finished the tutorial and got it working, but I am now running into the problem that I can't seem to update my database as per the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase

My goal: Add another String field to the todo item object.

My procedure: Add a column in the sql database for another String, add the new field into the serverside and clientside code.

The problem I am running into is that when I do this, it does not seem to work. When I select the option to update database in visual studio when publishing my service, it produces the below error.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know, thanks.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets(55,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\alexa\Source\Repos\campus_backend\ZUMOAPPNAMEService\App_Data\aspnet-ZUMOAPPNAMEService-ZUMOCURRENTDATE.mdf' as database 'aspnet-ZUMOAPPNAMEService-ZUMOCURRENTDATE'.)`